# Getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error while performing with axios on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios

I used nested request by using axios. Initially requesting POST request for the token with key/secrets and then trying to get results in following GET request by using previous request's token.

```
 var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: gsecConfig.tokenUrl,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: data
    };

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.access_token) {
                const config = {
                    headers: { Accept: 'application/json', Authorization: `Bearer ${response.data.access_token}` }
                };

                axios.get(gsecConfig.gsecUrl + gsecid, config)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        let supplierData = response.data;
                        res.status(200).json({
                            "data": supplierData
                        });
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        res.status(error.response.status || error.response).json({
                            "errors": [error.response.data]
                        });
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            res.status(error.response.status || error.response).json({
                "errors": [error.response.data]
            });
        });
```

while running the application getting below errors.

```
(node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
    at /whitelist-v1/nodejs/routes/gsec.js:47:39
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:32) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's highly likely your `error` doesn't have a `.response` member, making `error.response.status` failing. Errors *may* be decorated with `.response` only if they originate from the network - the standard `Error` object doesn't declare it.

So both catches should probably be more like:

```
res.status(error.response && error.response.status || 500).json({
  "errors": [error.response && error.response.data || error.message]
});
```

If it's not `error.response` that yields an `undefined`, then your `res` is `undefined`, which should be more obvious to catch.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts, you're right. We are requesting the token to third party platform. Getting the above error while the app is running on Docker container, since its not connecting with third party API. That is the reason for catch block issue.

We are looking into this issue .

"message": "socket hang up",
"name": "Error",
"stack": "Error: socket hang up\n    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)\n